# How to access mobile camera from ASP.NET MVC web application?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a ASP.NET MVC application that the website will eventually opened with a mobile browser. I am going to create a camera image button, where user can click on it and take picture and send to my web service. How can I achieve that?

I have tried to research many documents online but I could barely understand few of it. Will it be simple as camera.access() or there is a lot of complex algorithm behind? Appreciate if anyone can provide my some sample application or some valuable feedback.

Comment: Use WebRTC and make sure your application run at https (SSL).
https://github.com/nahidbinashraf/Capture-Image-From-Webcam-

Answer (score 0):

Go for WebRTC in your web application.